# insert text file content in drupal nodes

Tags: drupal

How I can do something like this:

```
drupal node content 1
[[[include /files/part2.txt]]]
drupal node content 3
```

and get node with file part1.txt content expanded.

*Why I need this:*

Very often I have some GIT repository which has to be presented on my website. The best would be to describe that repository from inside itself...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the PHP filter with the following code:

`<?php echo file_get_contents("/path/to/file"); ?>"`